# honeycomb down arrow not acting like back button

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, back-button, key-events

I am trying to port my Android app to work well on tablets with Honeycomb. One issue I am having is when the keyboard is showing and the back button turns into a down arrow, I can't seem to pick it up as not only a back button action, but as a keyevent in general. Here is my code:

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "keycode: " + event.getKeyCode());
}
```

So when the arrow is pointing down, I don't get a LogCat read out, and it appears it doesn't even know the down arrow is a KeyEvent. Has anyone else run into this? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is there to fix? That button hides the IME. Please allow your users to hide the IME.

Comment: I am allowing the users to hide the IME, but I also need to do a couple of additional things when the user touches the back button.

Comment: I suspect that you will need to revise your app to no longer require that you do those "couple of additional things" based on a hiding the IME. You might consider augmenting your question with details on what those "couple of additional things" are, so people can help you determine workarounds.

Comment: My keyboard is a fullscreen keyboard, so when I dismiss the keyboard, I need to put the text into the current application's text field.

Comment: If you are writing a custom IME, I would imagine that there are other events you should be using other than a BACK press to determine when you are supposed to be supplying the text back to the application. Otherwise, no custom IMEs would be working on Android 3.0+, and I would imagine that we would have heard about that by now. Admittedly, I have not (yet) created a custom IME, so I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the View.onKeyPreIme() method.

Although reading your question and your reply to Mark, I'm unsure as to whether you're writing an app or an input method.